# JavaScript comparing and filtering arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

My code gets the matches in array2.
I need array1's matches

So from array1 I am trying to get the numbers that match, i.e. 61, 35, 100.

Is this possible without major rewrites?

```
array1 = ["1x3","Purple","100","yes","no","61","4/4/14","no","35","Silver","yes"]

array2 = 
["id_2310", "35"]
["id_1223", "61"]
["id_8001", "100"]

newArray = consolidatedFilters(array2, array1);

function consolidatedFilters(passedArray, passedFilter) {
var filteredArray = passedArray.filter(
function(el) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < passedFilter.length; i++) { 
        if (el[1].indexOf(passedFilter[i]) != -1) {
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
);     
return filteredArray;
}
```

On a side note, Is comparing strings is a no-no? The way I have to populate array1 is with .innerHTML so it's all string

Comment: syntax errors.. array1 doesn't end with ; and array2 should not be declared in this way.. Also, array1 "yes" element should be last, so remove the "," after "yes" too

Comment: I should explain that the arrays up there are just a representation of the data that I'm working with. I'm not actually declaring them like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.map( function(item) { return item[1] })` to your `filter( )`